# Syntax Error on INNER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, inner-join

I get a error when trying to inner join databases from a MySqL server.

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lines INNER JOIN snippets ON snippets.id = lines.snippetid_fk WHERE lines.snippe' at line 1

Im Coding in ASP.Net C#.

This is my function that gives the error:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();

string mysql = "Server=***;Database=***;User=***;pwd=***";
conn.ConnectionString = mysql;

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM lines " +
                  "INNER JOIN snippets ON snippets.id = lines.snippetid_fk " +
                  "WHERE lines.snippetid_fk = 1";
cmd.Connection = conn;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

adapter.Fill(dt);

Repeater_codebank.DataSource = dt;
Repeater_codebank.DataBind();
```

Comment: what is the schema of your lines and snippets tables? is snippetid_fk a column in that table? Maybe you need to wrap all your object names with square brackets? `SELECT * FROM [lines] l INNER JOIN [snippets] s ON (s.id = l.snippetid_fk) WHERE l.snippetid_fk = 1`

Comment: @MohamedNuur - Square brackets definitely won't help. MySQL uses backticks. But you are basically correct `lines` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) so needs delimiting.

Comment: What happens if you try running the SQL directly in a query window?

Comment: I inserted line breaks in the commandtext so it can be viewed without scrolling. If you don't like it you are free to do a rollback.

Comment: Seems like it makes more sense to select from `snippets` first, and then get the associated `lines` records...

Comment: My Database i set up with 2 tables

first one i snippets where i have a id (int) and a snippet (varchar)
second is lines that has ID(int) tekst (text) snippetid_fk(int) and line(int)

Comment: Found the answer, apparantly MySql makes a fuss if you name a table "lines" :P but thanks for all the comments and all the help!

great community! :)

Comment: As per @MartinSmith's answer, in fact `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to documentation, `lines` is in the [list of MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

For your query, to work, you must add backticks around the table name:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `lines` " +
                  "INNER JOIN snippets ON snippets.id = lines.snippetid_fk " +
                  "WHERE `lines`.snippetid_fk = 1";
```